# setFormulas parse error

Tags: google-sheets

I'm getting a parse error with the following code:

```
var a = '=COUNTIF(' + b + ';"' + c + '")';
range.setFormula(a);
```

Where `b` is a `range` in `A1 notation` and `c` is a variable containing a `string comparator`

The code saves and compiles fine but I get a `parse error` in sheets.

The formula string itself appears to be written to the sheet appropriately (i.e. if I copy the formula in sheets and paste it into another cell it works without the error).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug because adding following code at the end of the code above fixed the problem:

```
range.setFormulas(range.getFormulas);
```